# How to download m3u8 playlist with URL redirection? (blob URL,HydraX, JW Player version 8.4.2)

Tags: ffmpeg, blob, jwplayer, youtube-dl

The video in https://hydrax.net/ is using HLS, .m3u8 file, direct link is https://hydrax.net/demo/hydrax.html (from the iframe src).

However, `youtube-dl` couldn't read from the .m3u8 file I downloaded from blob in chrome.

And using `ffmpeg` method (which usually works) to download from the .m3u8 file failed because the first segment of the file is a URL redirect

```
Error when loading first segment 'https://i.donald-gaines.xyz/redirect/7qC173pnWiDwe2TumUTYnzX4WdbPn8XJDzhqDzXPo39PWtX4EaAxLq7FLUW17aI/WhsiWh1RO6oSXzr6QqkTOgljgRrXBgpJtQf6gMBAC5Jq95JkuQlWKpfpgPoo/BSGGloj6MOe7cO4K9HoDj76PRzjSVoiwcJ1Xl34kc3Z5/Bl2WS3KO8WsicRVG8l1EBoi3RN2DnqZx6o13U56YnDBv'
2b0bdf87-656f-4880-8357-f7fd6329b2f8.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Somebody asked the same question in reddit some days ago: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Piracy/comments/dkoqp0/how_to_download_video_streaming_powered_by_jw/)